# Label is not showing in ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using `ChartJS` for my implementation of charts, but I notice that one of my graph's label is hidden. It is not showing its label above the bar. I've added a screenshot below for the comparison of two different bar graphs. The left graph shows the label even if it is on the very top but the other one is not showing. Please see my screenshot and code below.

```
function createChart(context, type, bgColor, bdColor, labels, actualData, options = {}){
    new Chart(context, {
        type: type,
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: "Actual",
                backgroundColor: bgColor,
                borderColor: bdColor,
                data: actualData,
            }]
        },

        options: options
    });
}


function getOptions(displayLegend = true){
    return {
      events: false,
         showTooltips: false,
         legend: {
             display: displayLegend
         },
         animation: {
             duration: 0,
             onComplete: function(){
                 var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
                 ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                 ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                 ctx.textBaseLine = 'bottom';
                 ctx.fillStyle = '#0b7707';

                 this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset){
                            console.log(dataset);
                     for(var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++){
                         for(var key in dataset._meta){
                             var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
                             ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 13);
                         }
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
     };
 }
```

[image]

Comment: both use the same css? it seems right one cuts the top side.

Comment: @ChaseChoi I didn't add any css for these except colors.

Comment: need more code to inspect the problem. and I'm not sure the label exists behind the legend because the part of legend is not showing on the right image.or you edit this fiddle to reproduce your issue. https://jsfiddle.net/Luaf2tm4/5973/

Comment: I edited it. Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/Luaf2tm4/5974/

Comment: I set the legend > display to `false`

Comment: It seems CharsJS bug on legend:false. what about to report an issue on their git repo? or try to set padding top on the chart.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding an empty title to the chart, so it will create space above the chart and show labels above the bar

```
options: {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: ' '
    },
....
```

Comment: I used this and it is work fine for me, thank you very much, i vote for this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a clear case of the datalabels going out of the canvas since the bar takes height dynamically as per the data values. You can set the max y-tick setting to solve this. Here is the jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/Luaf2tm4/5979/

Hope it helps!

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    borderWidth: 2,
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    data: [500, 2000, 800, 600, 950, 890],
  }]
};

function getOptions(displayLegend = false) {
  return {
    events: false,
    showTooltips: false,
    legend: {
      display: displayLegend
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
            stepSize: 200,
          min: 0, // minimum value
          max: 2200 // maximum value, you can either hard code if you know your datainput, else computer the value through some logic i.e taking the max value from the dataset and adding some extra value to it. 
        }
      }]
    },
    animation: {
      duration: 0,
      onComplete: function() {
        var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseLine = 'bottom';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#0b7707';

        this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
          console.log(dataset);
          for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
            for (var key in dataset._meta) {
              var model = dataset._meta[key].data[i]._model;
              ctx.fillText(dataset.data[i], model.x, model.y - 10);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  };
}

var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas, {
  data: data,
  options: getOptions()
});
```